# Как использовать одинаковые ключи в одном словаре?python

Tags: python, dict, key

У меня есть задание и мне нужно вывести команды по кол-во баллов. Ключом является название команды. Так вот как мне реализовать ввод одинаковых названий команд или проще, как мне использовать одинаковые ключи?

```
# создаем пустой словарь
teams = dict()
# кол-во команд
teams_count = input("Введите кол-во команд: ")

if not teams_count.isdigit():
    print('Введено неверное значение')
    quit()
else:
    teams_count = int(teams_count)

for x in range(teams_count):
    # название команды
    key = input("Введите название команды: ")
    
    # кол-во баллов у команды
    value = input("Введите кол-во очков: ")
    if not value.isdigit():
        print('Введено неверное значение')
        quit()
    else:
        value = int(value)

   # добавляем ключ со значением
    teams[key] = value

print(f"{max(teams, key=teams.get)} первое место")
sorted_teams = {k: v for k, v in sorted(teams.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}

i = 1
for x in sorted_teams:
    print(f"{x} заняла {i} место c баллом {sorted_teams[x]}")
    i += 1
```

Comment: Даже если бы это было возможно, как вы их планируете потом различать?

Comment: Словарь списков.

Comment: @Павел, я прекрасно понимаю, но мне дали такое задание. Могу ли я в принципе как-то реализовать вывод команд с одинаковым названием? Даже по логике звучит глупо, но в такой я ситуации.

Comment: @gdbwlrd например, использовать не словарь - а список списков, где в каждом элементе списка будет храниться список с название команды и количеством очков, либо использовать словарь списков, где в качестве ключа название команды, а значение - список, и если команда одна, то список из одного элемента с количеством баллов, если две - то два и т.д...